# Looking for a single ETF for maximum diversification

Tags: etf, europe, diversification, long-term

Around 5 years ago I started investing my savings by individually picking stocks with the intention of holding them. So basically Buy & Hold strategy mainly focusing on companies that pay dividend, but not restricted to them. I do cost averaging, by buying a fixed amount each 2 months of the stocks I want to have in my portfolio that I find cheap at that moment.

The strategy goes reasonably well, meaning that I can bear the market drops without suffering.

That being said, I am looking for an ETF in order to add another layer of diversification. Because I already try to pick individual stocks, I want an ETF that diversifies the most.

The problem I face is the huge amount of ETFs that one can find. For a product that is intended to diversify, it is really overwhelming such an offer of different products. The more I research, the more I find that people tend to hold different ETFs. Now, I just want one ETF, one to include them all, sort of.

Therefore, I am asking for a recommendation on which to choose (please bear in mind that I am investing from Europe). The closest to what I am looking for seems to be the Vanguard *FTSE All-World UCITS* ETF.

But then, as I said, there are lots of options, For example, *FTSE All-World High Dividend Yield UCITS* ETF looks interesting. But choosing this one would mean that I am favouring companies that pay a high dividend, Right?

So, in terms of diversification and for Buy & Hold, What would be the best ETF? I'm looking for maximum diversification across equities.

Comment: Google: "High Diversification ETFs" and you'll get some hits

Comment: Are you looking for just diversification across equities, or across other asset classes (fixed interest, alternatives etc) too?

Comment: That Vanguard FTSE All World ETF is the market leader in that niche – more diverse than ETFs following MSCI indexes, and close to zero tracking difference (low TD is more important than low TER). However, some people argue that it doesn't weigh emerging markets correctly, and that it excludes small caps, meaning that maximum diversification requires more than one ETF. How much dividends you want is primarily a tax question. I am Team A1JX52 because it matches my requirements, but might switch to the accumulating version for tax reasons in the future.

Comment: @timday I am looking for diversification across equities.

Comment: @amon The idea is to take the accumulating version, for now is much more tax efficient. If I need the dividends the idea is to switch to the distributing version.

Comment: Questions seeking product/service recommendations are specifically off-topic. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**VWRL** - Vanguard's FTSE All-World ETF - is a fine choice, and many investors will look no further.  According to Vanguard's info it buys you exposure to 3365 companies, includes emerging markets exposure (10.5%) and the top 3 holdings are Microsoft, Apple and Amazon at 2.6%, 2.58% & 1.66% respectively.

What can we find that's in some sense more diversified?

Smart-beta, yield-focussed or indeed any non-market cap weighted index tracker I'll dismiss as probably not increasing diversification but instead leading to "diworsifying" by under-weighting things you really ought to be holding to be maximally diversified.  So forget about anything but straight market-cap weighting.

**SWDA** - iShares Core MSCI World ETF - sounds promising.  But it only has 1645 holdings and no emerging markets exposure.  But that's down to MSCI World actually being limited to the developing world.  The one we actually need to look at is...

**SSAC** - iShares MSCI ACWI ETF (ACWI = All-Countries World Index).  That has 2292 holdings (still not as many as VWRL) but does have EM exposure (can't find it given as a percentage though).  The top three holdings are of course Microsoft, Apple and Amazon again, but note that the weights are 2.82%, 2.8% & 2.02%... higher than VWRL and reflecting the fact there are less holdings resulting in the value being more concentrated in the holdings the fund does have.

So, it looks like VWRL is the best you can get, at least if you equate diversification with number of holdings.

(ETF ticker codes above are for GBP-priced units on the UK market; maybe different elsewhere in Europe or for other currencies.)

However, as an example of what's possible it's interesting to look outside of ETFs... Vanguard do have a FTSE Global All Cap Index **Fund** which reaches further down into the mid-cap/small-cap end of global markets than the ETFs mentioned above do, and consequently has more holdings.  The fund has an incredible 6500 holdings, includes EM exposure, and the top three holdings (Microsoft, Apple and Amazon again) have weights of 2.29%, 2.27% & 1.46%, a bit lower than VWRL's and reflecting the fact there are many more holdings for the fund to spread its value across.

But really all these things will move pretty much together and it'll make little difference which you pick.  Real diversification would come with exposure to other (non-equity) asset classes.

In fact I'll throw in a chart (Trustnet's data, total return, GBP prices) just to illustrate the sort of variation there's been over the last few years (chart's range is limited by the relatively short lifetime of the Vanguard FTSE Global All Cap Fund):

[image: Global trackers]

Those chart lines are pretty much on top of each other.  Closer inspection of the numbers underneath does actually show that it's the *least* diversified trackers with the *least* holdings which have done the best over this timescale; this is explainable by the tech megacorps being the star performers over the period, so trackers with less mid-cap/small-cap exposure and more crowding into the tech giants have done better.  Whether that'll be the same in future... who knows?

To get a longer term view, looking at the relevant indices for as far back as Trustnet will let me chart them (NB total return, GBP terms) shows the bigger picture and actually very little difference between the most and least diversified of those indices over the last ten years, although the outperformance of the FTSE Global All Cap over the full period of the chart is intriguing.

[image: Global indices]

Answer (score 2):

The best diversification is obtained by accepting all stocks and not restricting you to just high dividend yield stocks.

High dividend yield stocks occur mostly in sectors such as oil production that are dying. No growth opportunities, and therefore, investors demand the return in the form of dividends only.

Why would you want to restrict yourself to just dying sectors only?

Definitely pick the ETF that does not arbitrarily restrict itself to just high dividend yield stocks. So I would recommend the Vanguard *FTSE All-World UCITS* ETF. Or some other equivalent to it. I think this is not the place to discuss which provider to select. But this is the place to underline that high dividend yield stocks only in the portfolio does not make sense.