# Buying Vanguard Total World Stock ETF in Germany via Flatex

Tags: stocks, etf, stock-analysis, germany

I would like to invest in ETFs via an online broker in Germany (I use Flatex). I would like to buy an ETF tracking the [MSCI World Index](https://www.msci.com/documents/10199/149ed7bc-316e-4b4c-8ea4-43fcb5bd6523).

The two main options I am considering are Vanguard Total World Stock ETF ([NYSE “VT"](https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/profile/VT)) and IShares MSCI World ETF (“[URTH](https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239696/ishares-msci-world-etf)”). 
I know that Vanguard’s World ETF is not exactly tracking MSCI, but it is [very close](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/etfs-mutual-funds/071516/top-3-etfs-tracking-msci-world-index-urth-vt.asp) – and considering the lower fees, I would prefer to go for this option.

When I search for Vanguard Total World Stock in Flatex I only get Vanguard t.wld st.idx.  Is this equivalent to NYSE’s “VT”?

Comment: That Vanguard fund tracks the FTSE Global All Cap Index.  Which is arguably a "better index" than MSCI World, at least if you wanted more diversification into smaller capitalization companies and emerging markets.  More on this in this answer: https://money.stackexchange.com/a/123809/35887 .

Comment: Thanks @timday, that makes sense, but is "Vanguard t.wld st.idx" in flatex the same as VWRL?

Comment: Not sure as I only know about Vanguard's products in the UK and I know nothing about flatex.  However I do know that over here their VWRL ETF tracks the FTSE All World index.  And there are no "Total World" named products here, but when I google that name I only find the US ETF tracking the FTSE Global AllCap index.  If they're tracking different indices, obviously they're different things.